# Responsive scaling for mobile websites to have full phone width

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

Assuming all elements in the body can be stretched to 100% - Besides doing something like this:

```
body {
     overflow-x:hidden;
     width:320px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 360px) {
    body {
        width:360px;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 369px) {
    body {
        width:369px;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        width:480px;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 533px) {
    body {
        width:533px;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 569px) {
    body {
        width:569px;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 640px) {
    body {
        width:640px;
    }
}
```

Is there a better / less hard-coded approach than the above?

Also, there are mixed views about using this in mobile:

```
<meta content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

Read that the initial scale (bug) between portrait and landscape has been fixed in iOS 6 for iPad and hence the above is no longer needed...

But can I assume this is still needed in new and old iPhones as well as other mobile devices from Android and Samsung?

Comment: As much as media queries bring about a great deal of flexibility. I believe that specific device/model detection is non-ideal for maintainability as there will just be more and more different dimension-specifications to cater to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. All the media queries are **not needed** for website full width (although this is quite an extensive list that covers most devices).

Just the below is sufficient as I initially planned (the overflow-x is just insurance):

```
body {
     overflow-x:hidden;
     width:100%;
}
```

However I had an 2nd level nav element with position:absolute, left:100% and width:100%, which was distorting the actual website-width on the phone (resulting in a really wide website, probably as wide as the phone's resolution).

Once the left position of the element is only set by JavaScript (instead of being read by the phone on initial website load), the problem resolved.

Lesson learnt is take care with position absolute elements on mobile, even with overflow hidden, these may distort actual site width recognised by the phone.

I also had to include the meta viewport for phones... 
Although widely accepted as the answer for iPad website scaling as well, having width=device-width and initial scale actually screwed up my website scaling between portrait-landscape-portrait on the iPad (latest OS).

Not having it meant the scaling works perfectly! Need to test on iPhone (latest OS) to determine if it behaves like the iPad (where the orientation bug is meant to be fixed).

```
<meta name="viewport" content=""/>
<script>
if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
    var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
    if (viewportmeta) {
        viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1';
    }
}
</script>
```